# How to get python to detect a space in a dictionary from an imported txt file?

Tags: python, dictionary, translation

Okay, the problem I have here is that I've got this .txt file Python imports into a dictionary.

What is does is it takes the values from the text files, that are in this Specific format:

```
a 0.01                   
b 0.11
c 1.11
d 0.02
```

^ (In code format because It wouldn't wouldn't stack it like in the .txt, not actually code)
and then puts them into a dictionary like this:

d = { 'a':'0.01', 'b':'0.11, ect....}

Well, I'm using this so that it will change whatever value the user inputs (Later in the script) into whatever is defined inside the dictionary.

The problem is if I try and make it incorporate a space, it just doesn't work.

Like, I finished the letters, and their corresponding values in the .txt and began going onto symbols:

For example:

```
& &
* *
```

(so that when entered into the dictionary, the corresponding values are printed when I have it print the translated message) (I could change them up, but I decided to leave them as they are)

The problem arises when I try and have it make a space in the user input correspond to a space or another value in the translated message.

I tried leaving a row blank in my .txt, so that (space) is to (space)

But later, when it tried to load the .txt, it gave me an error, saying that: "need more than one value to unpack"

Can someone help me out?

EDIT:  Adding code as requested.

```
TRvalues = {}
with open(r"C:\Users\Owatch\Documents\Python\Unisung Net Send\nsed.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        TRvalues[key] = val
if TRvalues == False:
    print("\n\tError encountered while attempting to load the .txt file")
    print("\n\t The file does not contain any values")
else:
    print("Dictionary Loaded-")
```

Sample text file:

```
a 0.01
b 0.11
c 1.11
d 0.02
e 0.22
f 2.22
g 0.03
h 0.33
i 3.33
j 0.04
k 0.44
l 4.44
m 0.05
n 0.55
o 5.55
p 0.06
q 0.66
r 6.66
s 0.07
t 0.77
u 7.77
v 0.08
w 0.88
x 8.88
y 0.09
z 0.99
```

I get this error when I attempt to run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owatch/Documents/Python/Unisung Net Send/Input Encryption 0.02.py", line 17, in <module>
    (key, val) = line.split()
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

EDIT: **Thanks for downvoting everybody! I'm now no longer able to ask questions.**

Believe it or not I DO know the rules for this website, and DID research this before asking on Stack Overflow. It IS helpful for other people as well. What a nice community. Hopefully the people who answered did not downvote it. I appreciate what they did.

Comment: how are you taking the input?

Comment: You need to show the code.

Comment: You still haven't given the failing case.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Do you mean that the space must be the failing case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to use a space both as an unquoted value and as a delimiter, which won't work.  I'd use the `csv` module and its quoting rules.  For example (assuming you're using Python 3 from your `print` functions):

```
import csv

with open('nsed.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader((line.strip() for line in f), delimiter=' ')
    TRvalues = dict(reader)

print(TRvalues)
```

with an input file of

```
a 0.01
b 0.11
c 1.11
d 0.02
" " " "
```

gives

```
{' ': ' ', 'a': '0.01', 'b': '0.11', 'c': '1.11', 'd': '0.02'}
```

Comment: To make it more robust against unescaped whitespace in the input: `csv.reader((line.strip() for line in f), delimiter=' ')`

Comment: I get this instead: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #27 has length 5; 2 is required

Comment: Owatch: then you must have a line with 5 elements, which means you had a line with multiple spaces that you didn't quote, like `this is a bad example`, which should be something like `this "is a good example"`.  Is it the `" " " "` line?  That shouldn't happen with the code I gave.

Comment: I just entered what you told me the input should resemble, with " " " " I am just confused

Comment: Yes, it is specifically that line.

Comment: Ah, then you may have added extra spaces at the end.  Try `reader = csv.reader((line.strip() for line in f), delimiter=' ')`, and make sure there's no blank line at the end of the file.  Remember that since you're using spaces as a delimiter, every unquoted space in the file tells Python -- whether you're using `.split()` or `csv` or whatever -- that you have an extra column of data.

Comment: You were right, I fixed that problem, let me see if it works.    It appears to be working. That's pretty great. Unfortunately I don't understand what exactly was done. But it works. Thanks much.

Comment: If it's the `csv` module that's puzzling you, the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) give a nice little example.  If it's the change to the reader which is confusing, `(line.strip() for line in f)` is called a generator expression, and here it's an object which says "for every line in the file `f`, remove the whitespace from each side".  Then we pass that object into the reader instead of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're in effect trying to do.

```
In [177]: "a b".split()
Out[177]: ['a', 'b']

In [178]: "  ".split()
Out[178]: []
```

i.e. have a blank line and expect the spaces to be preserved when doing a split() but that won't work.

Therefore `k, v = line.split()` won't work.

**EDIT** Presuming I understand the problem.

Perhaps you need to encode the values when you put them in the file and then decode on the way out.

A naive approach might be to use `urrlib.quote` and `urllib.unquote`

On the write.

```
In [188]: urllib.quote(' ')
Out[188]: '%20'
```

Which makes it a bit trickier for the special case of <kbd>space</kbd> unless you do for all values on the write to the file.

```
fd.write("%s %s\n" % (urllib.encode(val1), urllib.encode(val2)))
```

Then on the read from the file.

```
k,v = map(urrlib.unquote, lines.split())
```

Comment: What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I suggest you do what @DSM suggests the ``csv`` module has these thing covered. You'll always come upon the issue where you need to use you delimiter as data and that's covered with ``csv``.